# Attempting to Create HTML Table from SQL database table

Tags: html, sql

I am trying to extract the 300+ account names from some software we use thru SQL and have it give me a list of customers that I can use in a drop down in our internal inventory control PHP page.  I believe that I have the basic form of the code down, I just need some help gluing it together.  This is what I have so far (note: I am just trying to get it to spit out the names for now, don't worry about making it a drop down)

Test.PHP reads

```
$con=mysqli_connect("Server","username","password","Database");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM AccountName");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['AccountName'] . " " . $row['AccountName'];
  echo "<br>";
  }
mysqli_close($con);
```

I believe that that is good, but I am having trouble trying to get it to actually produce the results.  I don't think I am understanding it correctly.

Test.html reads

```
<HTML>
<body>
mysqli_fetch_array($row['AccountName'])
</body>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: But what's the problem? You get any errors or the behavior is unexpected?

Comment: Is that your actually your current HTML? Or is that a copy-paste error

Comment: When I exicute the PHP file, it just asks me where I want to save it, the HTML file just doesn't come up with anything.

Comment: The first thing I see is that you are trying to generate PHP code into a HTML file?